# GeoPandas GeoDataFrame Transformation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transformation, geopandas

Dear stackoverflow community,

I spent the past few weeks reading through documentations and articles all around Python, Pandas and GeoPandas. Sadly programming still isn't as intuetively to me as I wish and since I dont come from a programming background dealing with GeoPandas is a pure nightmare for me.

I have a rather complex ( for me at least ) `geopandas.GeoDataFrame` that I need to transform to do further regression analysis. Sadly even after countless searches here on stackoverflow and numerous other internet pages I still can not transform my data in a suitable manner.

---

**My GeoDataFrame looks as follows:**

```
         INCIDENTDATE       CATEGORY_left    CATEGORY_right  \
POLYGON                                                       
1                2009            BURGLARY        restaurant   
1                2009            HOMICIDE        restaurant   
1                2010             ASSAULT        restaurant   
1                2011             ASSAULT        restaurant   
1                2012             LARCENY        restaurant   
1                2012  AGGRAVATED ASSAULT        restaurant   
1                2012            BURGLARY        restaurant   
1                2012  DAMAGE TO PROPERTY        restaurant   
1                2013  AGGRAVATED ASSAULT        restaurant   
1                2014            BURGLARY        restaurant   
3                2010  MURDER/INFORMATION          crossing   
3                2011  AGGRAVATED ASSAULT          crossing   
3                2011            BURGLARY          crossing   
3                2011             ASSAULT          crossing   
3                2012  AGGRAVATED ASSAULT          crossing   
3                2012  MURDER/INFORMATION          crossing   
3                2013     DANGEROUS DRUGS          crossing   
3                2014  DAMAGE TO PROPERTY          crossing   
3                2015             ASSAULT          crossing   

                                                  geometry    shape_area  
POLYGON                                                                   
1        POLYGON ((-83.13630642653472 42.43895550416347...  3.959841e+06  
1        POLYGON ((-83.13630642653472 42.43895550416347...  3.959841e+06  
1        POLYGON ((-83.13630642653472 42.43895550416347...  3.959841e+06  
1        POLYGON ((-83.13630642653472 42.43895550416347...  3.959841e+06  
1        POLYGON ((-83.13630642653472 42.43895550416347...  3.959841e+06  
1        POLYGON ((-83.13630642653472 42.43895550416347...  3.959841e+06  
1        POLYGON ((-83.13630642653472 42.43895550416347...  3.959841e+06  
1        POLYGON ((-83.13630642653472 42.43895550416347...  3.959841e+06  
1        POLYGON ((-83.13630642653472 42.43895550416347...  3.959841e+06  
1        POLYGON ((-83.13630642653472 42.43895550416347...  3.959841e+06  
3        POLYGON ((-83.17870657596477 42.39269734838572...  3.918602e+06  
3        POLYGON ((-83.17870657596477 42.39269734838572...  3.918602e+06  
3        POLYGON ((-83.17870657596477 42.39269734838572...  3.918602e+06  
3        POLYGON ((-83.17870657596477 42.39269734838572...  3.918602e+06  
3        POLYGON ((-83.17870657596477 42.39269734838572...  3.918602e+06  
3        POLYGON ((-83.17870657596477 42.39269734838572...  3.918602e+06  
3        POLYGON ((-83.17870657596477 42.39269734838572...  3.918602e+06  
3        POLYGON ((-83.17870657596477 42.39269734838572...  3.918602e+06  
3        POLYGON ((-83.17870657596477 42.39269734838572...  3.918602e+06
```

---

`'CATEGORY_left'` is a `geopandas.GeoDataFrame` that was joined using `geopandas.sjoin` and geometry points. It contains different categories of crime related incidents and looks like this:

### **`'CATEGORY_left'`**

```
     INCIDENTDATE          CATEGORY                            geometry
0          2009             LARCENY  POINT (-83.06870000000001 42.3516)
1          2009             ASSAULT            POINT (-82.9504 42.4262)
2          2009             ASSAULT            POINT (-83.2657 42.4371)
3          2009  DAMAGE TO PROPERTY  POINT (-83.03189999999999 42.4381)
4          2009      STOLEN VEHICLE            POINT (-83.1499 42.4094)
```

`'CATEGORY_right'` is also a `geopandas.GeoDataFrame` that I joined with `geopandas.sjoin` aswell. It contains different Points of Interest that are dependent only to the `'POLYGON'` their in. They dont change over time.

### **`'CATEGORY_right'`**

```
          CATEGORY                                          geometry
13243          atm      POINT (-83.06221670000002 42.32472120000001)
13244          atm                    POINT (-83.0711901 42.3213266)
13245          atm             POINT (-83.0232692 42.34089829999999)
24624  supermarket             POINT (-83.2400998 42.37158820000001)
24625  supermarket                    POINT (-82.9728123 42.3872246)
```

---

In order to do regression analysis I need it to be in the following shape.

### Final:

```
         INCIDENTDATE       TOTAL_CRIME_COUNT    RESTAURANT_COUNT\
POLYGON                                                       
1                2009                    4396                 30
1                2010                    6455                 30
1                2011                    7434                 30
1                2012                    3843                 30
1                2013                    5354                 30
1                2014                    3425                 30
3                2010                    4564                 10
3                2011                    3234                 10
3                2012                    8754                 10
3                2013                    4829                 10
3                2014                    9583                 10
3                2015                    4354                 10

                                                  geometry    shape_area  
POLYGON                                                                   
1        POLYGON ((-83.13630642653472 42.43895550416347...  3.959841e+06  
1        POLYGON ((-83.13630642653472 42.43895550416347...  3.959841e+06  
1        POLYGON ((-83.13630642653472 42.43895550416347...  3.959841e+06  
1        POLYGON ((-83.13630642653472 42.43895550416347...  3.959841e+06  
1        POLYGON ((-83.13630642653472 42.43895550416347...  3.959841e+06  
1        POLYGON ((-83.13630642653472 42.43895550416347...  3.959841e+06  
1        POLYGON ((-83.13630642653472 42.43895550416347...  3.959841e+06  
1        POLYGON ((-83.13630642653472 42.43895550416347...  3.959841e+06  
1        POLYGON ((-83.13630642653472 42.43895550416347...  3.959841e+06  
1        POLYGON ((-83.13630642653472 42.43895550416347...  3.959841e+06  
3        POLYGON ((-83.17870657596477 42.39269734838572...  3.918602e+06  
3        POLYGON ((-83.17870657596477 42.39269734838572...  3.918602e+06  
3        POLYGON ((-83.17870657596477 42.39269734838572...  3.918602e+06  
3        POLYGON ((-83.17870657596477 42.39269734838572...  3.918602e+06  
3        POLYGON ((-83.17870657596477 42.39269734838572...  3.918602e+06  
3        POLYGON ((-83.17870657596477 42.39269734838572...  3.918602e+06  
3        POLYGON ((-83.17870657596477 42.39269734838572...  3.918602e+06  
3        POLYGON ((-83.17870657596477 42.39269734838572...  3.918602e+06  
3        POLYGON ((-83.17870657596477 42.39269734838572...  3.918602e+06
```

**What is important to note:**

1. The rows are aggregated by same values in `'INCIDENTDATE'`
2. The sum of total crime incidents per polygon per year is taken in the column `'TOTAL_CRIME_COUNT'`
3. The sum of a distinct Points of Interest ist taken for each Polygon. Every 
   Point of Interest need to be in its own column.

I would be so happy even for the slightest hint to a solution.
I am also open to completely different approaches to reach my final DataFrame, since im not even sure if I'm doing it the right way to begin with.

Thank you very much if you made it this far!

Charles

P.S.: I apologize for grammar mistakes. English is not my first language.

Comment: Is there any reason why you keep both as geodataframe instead of converting them to dataframe? If you don't need to do spatial regression or GWR, etc, you may want to convert them to dataframe and then use `groupby` function. Btw, I'm a little bit confused by your workflow. Could you please make it a little bit clear about how many datasets you have and what you wanna for the final dataframe?

Comment: I just read it through again. You need an ID column to identify each case in both of your point geodataframe and an ID column to identify each polygon in your polygon geodataframe before `sjoin()` so that those cases will be indefinable after that. And then you can `groupby` your final dataframe based on the year and polygon ID while count the number of unique value of case ID, which will give you the total number of case in each polygon in each year.